# Export github project to csv

Tags: github

Since 2022, Github [features a second attempt on "Projects"](https://github.blog/2022-07-27-planning-next-to-your-code-github-projects-is-now-generally-available/).

How can I export a table view of such an v2 project to a csv file?

#### Example

This is an example, which I would like to export to csv:
https://github.com/users/fiedl/projects/2/views/1

[image: table screenshot]

#### Further resources

- [Blog post on github projects](https://github.blog/2022-07-27-planning-next-to-your-code-github-projects-is-now-generally-available/)
- [Projects documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects)
- [API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/using-the-api-to-manage-projects)
- I have found this node project https://github.com/justinmahar/github-projectv2-csv-exporter, but maybe there is also a built-in endpoint or some cli tool

Answer (score 3):

### Workaround: Export all project items as csv

Based on the [github cli](https://cli.github.com) and [github's projects api](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/automating-your-project/using-the-api-to-manage-projects), I have created a script to export all project items into a csv file as a temporary workaround.

Repo: https://github.com/fiedl/github-project-to-csv

```
brew install gh
git clone https://github.com/fiedl/github-project-to-csv.git

./github-project-to-csv.rb --project https://github.com/users/fiedl/projects/2 --output project.csv
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**GitHub Project CSV Exporter v2** can do this:

- [github](https://github.com/justinmahar/github-projectv2-csv-exporter)
- [documentation](https://justinmahar.github.io/github-projectv2-csv-exporter/?path=/story/home--page)

It can be cloned and run locally but I've had great success with the [in-browser tool](https://justinmahar.github.io/github-projectv2-csv-exporter/?path=/story/tools-github-project-exporter--exporter).